# How read an annotation file?

Tags: java, file, class, annotations

I dont'know that, how can I read a file. I would like to read the FK.java file, but give me a class not found exception. FK is annotation java file. (I have tried "src/annotations/FK.java" but didn't work.

```
private static String clazz = "src/annotations/FK";

public static List<Object> GetAnnotations() throws ClassNotFoundException{

    Class<?> c;
    c = Class.forName(clazz);

    List<Object> result = new ArrayList();


    Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++)
    {
        Annotation[] annot = fields[j].getAnnotations();
        for (int k = 0; k < annot.length; k++)
        {
            result.add(annot[k].annotationType());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println(GetAnnotations());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the class should contain dots (`.`) not slashes (`'/`')

```
private static String clazz = "annotations.FK";
```

Then

```
Class.forName(clazz);
```

will try to load the *class* `annotations/FK.class` from the provided classpath.  If you only have the .java file, you will need to compile it first.

EDIT: fixed path based on comments

Comment: src/ is probably the source folder, so the class name is likely annotations.FK

Comment: Thanks, It can be read the file :) But somebody have got some tutorial, how can I read out the annotation? My code don't work...

Comment: @blaces - "don't work" is hard to decipher.  Please give us more details

Comment: @blaces You're being pretty vague. Could you perhaps provide a source code sample of your annotated class?

Comment: :) Yes. Here is the `@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface FK {

    public Class<?> value();
} `

Comment: @blaces - your annotation is on the interface, but your code is looking for annotations on fields.  Try calling `getAnnotations()` on `c` or on the types returned by `c.getInterfaces()`

Comment: Attila if you are hungarian: lehet még kérdésem? :) Ha felteszem egy külön kérdésben, segítesz? :)

Comment: @blaces - It's best to keep to English on this site :)  If you post your question in a new post, and don't get an answer shortly, post the link to the new question here, so I'm notified

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you're trying to get the Class object for your annotated class with the wrong syntax.

The `Class.forName(String)`-method takes a fully qualified Java class name as a parameter. That is the name of the package containing the class as declared in your Java-file immediately followed by your class name. In your case that is probably `"annotations.FK"`.

An other note is that simply having the Java-source code file for the class will not do. You will need to have the compiled class in your classpath.

Here is a simple example:

```
// mytoplevelpackage/mypackage/MyClass.java

package mytoplevelpackage.mypackage;

public class MyClass {}


// mytoplevelpackage/OtherClass.java

package mytoplevelpackage;

public class OtherClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class c = Class.forName("mytoplevelpackage.mypackage.MyClass");
  }
}
```